# Fastest way to perform this? Ternary Operator? Switch? Array?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, if-statement, ternary-operator

What is the fastest way to perform this? The vars in the parens on the left return boolean and they represent window size ranges. (e.g. `o1281` returns `true` for screens 1281 and up, `o1025` returns `true` for 1025 and up, etc.)

```
markup = // ternary triangle (the rows set the markup priority at each band)
    ( o1281 ) ? r1281 || r1025 || r961 || r641 || r481 || r320 || r0 || omarkup: 
        ( o1025 ) ? r1025 || r961 || r641 || r481 || r320 || r0 || omarkup: 
            ( o961 ) ? r961 || r641 || r481 || r320 || r0 || omarkup: 
                ( o641 ) ? r641 || r481 || r320 || r0 || omarkup: 
                    ( o481 ) ? r481 || r320 || r0 || omarkup: 
                        ( o320 ) ? r320 || r0 || omarkup: 
                            ( o0 ) ? r0 || omarkup: 
                                omarkup;
```

I was thinking maybe break it into 2 ranges based on the middle (`o641`) condition.

Is it worth it?

Comment: How should anyone understand this? What is `rxxx`?

Comment: The r### values are all `var`'s. For example they might be image urls and the higher numbers represent higher resolution images. The `omarkup` is the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so what you are doing is looking for the first truthy o-value going in descending order, and once you find one you are looking for the first truthy r-value whose name is `<=` this o-value.  Finding none, you wish to return the value `omarkup`.

Because you only have a few o-values and r-values, your code, as "interesting" as it may be, appears to make the least number of tests possible.

I can't see how switches or hashes would help, since you do appear to be searching in descending order for the first truthy value....  Because of this, I don't see why splitting would help performance either.  Leave it as is, or, if you prefer readability (as many programmers do), make objects for which 1281, 1025, etc. are *fields*.

Also, worrying about performance is usually something one does when faced with an operation that will executed many, many times.  Is this the case here?  This looks like something you would only execute once, assuming the o and r values don't change.  (Just an FYI.)

**ADDENDUM**

Based on the comment added to the question above, it looks like an operation you *would* like to execute multiple times.  In this case it probably okay to self-optimize at the JavaScript level, although modern compilers are pretty good.  The biggest concern from a code-review perspective would be that the values 1281, 1025, 961, 941, and so on are laid out manually and are part of the source code, so maintenance, such as adding new size-values here is, well, tricky and error-prone.  That said, based on what you have shown, I think it is safe to say your JavaScript as written is the best obtainable given a naive compiler.  You can always shoot for an implementation that defines these values exactly once and then profile it to see if it is "fast enough".  For example you can define an array such as

```
var sizes = [1281,1025,961,641,481,320,0]
```

and loop through, but yes, there is overhead in such implementations.

One issue that might help you here is to consider carefully what can and cannot be cached.  This could help speed up future executions of this code.

Comment: Thx It needs to occur when the DOM is ready and inside a `.resize` function (so it would occur anytime a browser window is resized or when a smartphone is rotated.) See the full thing here: http://responsejs.com/source/v0/

Comment: I realized I could merge the last two lines of the triangle simply into `r0 || omarkup; // 0-319` because at that point we know we're below 320 and we know those are the only two values that work there.

Comment: @ryanve I see. Yes, efficiency is important during resize and reflow.  I added a comment to my answer.

Comment: Nice/thanks again. Good points. (I definitely was using find and replace when editing it:) I don't imagine the need to add tons more points, but maybe a few. (Those are meant to be breakpoints for responsive design.) The r values and the triangle are both in the same `.each` function (inside the resize). The r values are pulled from data attributes and the `.each` is needed to retrieve and apply the value for each element. Although in practice, only some of the attributes would prob. be in use at a time.

Comment: I like the idea with the array too. I'm going to experiment with that.

Comment: Maybe a hybrid could be to define the size array but then type out  `sizes[2] || sizes[1] || sizes[0]` etc. manually rather than running as a loop. You think?

Comment: That is indeed somewhere _between_ what you have and working down the values with a for-loop.  If it meets your performance criteria it is fine.  The general rule is to be as readable and maintainable as possible, but if you get into a situation where your compiler cannot help you, and you **must** increase performance, do so.  Okay maybe that is an oversimplification but it is a good starting point....  In any case, I think it is fair to say it is easier to debug 3, 2, 1, 0 than multiple versions of 1281,1025,961,641. :)

Comment: I tried a version with the o values and the r values in arrays. Definitely more readable. But I'm going to use the all local vars version because it is faster. Not only does it compresses smaller, but it avoids the array lookups. The local vars are faster. I might just adjust their names to be more 'array like' for maintainability.